# Not able to trigger main error handler in my node express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using node express (4.15.2), with the default error handler created using express generator function to handle errors.

The code is:

```
const app = express();
app.set('port', config.enviroment.portNumber);
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, config.client.app)));

app.post(config.route.postUploads, uploader.onUpload);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // this function is never called
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  const port = server.address().port;
});
```

In my application I using the following line of code when I need to create an error:

```
new Error('Some custom error');
```

But the error handler is never called.

Notes: the error handler is placed after the latest `app.use` but before `app.listen`.

Any ideas what could cause this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a straightforward solution to my problem, basically I had to use

`throw new Error('Some custom error');`

In general express follows the way of passing errors rather than throwing it, for any errors in the program it could be a good idea to pass the error object to 'next' , and using and error handler so that all the errors passed to next can be handled properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the said function at the very bottom of the code because ordering of routes matters (see this[enter link description here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)). Also, you need to `throw` your error like so `throw new Error('Custom error')` in order to trigger the error in your app.

Comment: I have edited my question adding full source code, unfortunately I was not able to fix this issue using your answer... any other ideas?

Comment: were you using the generated express.js app and didn't modify anything? A screenshot of your console or browser would help